# HTTP POST to Microsoft DevOps API Returns 404

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I have carefully followed the documentation outlined [here by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to create a Bug in Dev Ops via the API. The documentation is well written.

Steps followed:

1. In Dev Ops I created a Personal Access Token, the string value of which I converted to Base64.
2. In a separate Power Automate flow, I composed a list of the projects in my target DevOps Organization for testing purposes. The JSON for the projects in this Organization is as follows:

   [image: Project Details]
3. Now if I copy and paste this URL (in the picture above) into my browser it resolves correctly.
4. I created a Postman HTTP POST Request with the following details:
5. URL: `https://dev.azure.com/{my org}/{Demo guid}/_apis/wit/workitems/{{taskType}}?api-version=7.0`
6. Under Authorization I set the Bearer Token and pasted in my encoded PAT
7. The JSON Body is as follows:

[image: RequestBody]

6. The POSTMAN variable in the URL ***taskType*** is set to Bug

The request Headers are as follows:

[image: Request Headers]

7. Once again please note that if I paste the URL (1) in green into a browser it resolves correctly. However, the request returns a **404 Page not found**.

I cannot understand why it is not finding the page, as I would expect a not authorized error if the problem was with the token.

Comment: you should get something like this otherwise your URL is likely borked, check the docs ->
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "VS402323: Work item type BLAH does not exist in project 123456789-7213-40fe-a703-4b19c027241b or you do not have permission to access it.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.WorkItemTypeNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
    "typeKey": "WorkItemTypeNotFoundException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3200
}

Comment: I think the issue is that i need to include a $ symbol before the taskType e.g.
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.0

Comment: I am not getting 203 Non-Authoritative Information after adding the $ before {{taskType }} which is working now, a different problem of authentication needs to be addressed which is out of the scope of this original submission.

Comment: Forget using the Bearer token...Go to the tab "Authorization" > choose type, "Basic auth", then leave the username blank and paste a valid PAT token in the password. Then remove the Bearer token before trying again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have `{{taskType}}` as a literal in your URL string.

Just try to perform a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-item-types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to find all the valid `taskTypes`. Also drop the Bearer token and just use Basic Auth to keep it simple. The username should be empty and password should contain your AzDO PAT.
[image]

Comment: The auth issue was solved using your approach above. The string literal is a Postman variable that is substituted on submission of the request and did not cause an issue. The auth solution was to select Basic Auth with no user name and the PAT as the password. 

Using Version 7.0 of the API I need to include a '$' symbol before the taskType. This solved the 404 issue.

Comment: Awesome. Please mark this as the answer to help others having similar issues

Answer (score 0):

Needed to include the $ symbol. I am now getting authentication issues but this is outside the scope of the original submission.

[image: Postman URL]

[image: Sample Request]

Comment: {project} needs to be the name of a project in your AzDO organization. Then drop ${type} from your request for now. This response should be a list of available types you can then use.